# Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core with String parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to set up the routing in my project so that I can have a URL like */Account/Profile/FrankReynolds* instead of having to do */Account/Profile?name=FrankReynolds*. If I try and hit the URL `/Account/Profile/FrankReynolds` the name parameter is coming through as *NULL*.

This is the `IActionResult` on the `Account` controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile(string name, string filter = null, int? page = null)
{ .... }
```

In my `Program.cs` I am currently using the following:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "AccountDefault",
    pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Profile}/{name}"
);
```

Comment: Is a route of `Account/Profile/{name}` instead working for you?

Comment: Without the controller=, action = parts?

Comment: Using that as a pattern

Comment: Nope that still comes through as null

Comment: @BadDub: Do you have any attributes applied to the controller class or action methods? If not, try to clean up your browser cache and try again.

Comment: Nope I dont not have any attributes on the controller or actionresult. Still passes null through.

Comment: @BadDub: This is strange, because of this working for me.  What .NET version you are using?

Comment: I am using .NET 6.0

Comment: Have you tried to add route attribute like `[HttpGet("Account/Profile/{name?}")]` to that endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update the `IActionResult` with the `HttpGet` attribute that included the URL path and the parameter name and also add the `FromRoute` attribute just before the `name` parameter.

```
[HttpGet("Account/Profile/{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile([FromRoute] string name, string filter = null, int? page = null)
{ .... }
```

Comment: I think instead of hardcoding `Account/Profile/{name}`, you can still just say `[HttpGet("[controller]/[action]/{name}")]`.

And as long as {name} matches the parameter `string name`, you shouldn't need `[FromRoute]` per se, although being explicit isn't a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

If your controller is named `AccountController` and the action method is named `Profile`, the pattern you can use is something like this:

`pattern: {controller}/{action}/{name}`

If that indeed doesn't work out, attributes on the controller class and methods should definitely work.

I suggest using the following attributes:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
. . .
[HttpGet("{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile(string name, string filter = null, int? page = null)
```

For this to work, you'll likely have to use the default controller router in your Program.cs/Startup.cs as `app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();`.

In general, I do suggest configuring routing on controllers and action methods instead of bloating the startup. It gives you much finer control over each of your actions and the routing you want for them.

Comment: I have tagged the controller with ApiController and the Route attribute. I also used the HttpGet attribute along with commenting out the routing code in the program.cs class. It seems to be working now. I will give it some more testing now.

Comment: Also what does ApiController do when its not an API but a web page?

Comment: This did work but it seemed to mess with the other ActionResults in the project so I could use it

Comment: @BadDub it messes up the other ActionResults in the project because you took out the routing code in the Program.cs?